# How do I extend to convert an integer to a character by using the 'chr()' function, and output that character

Tags: python

I'm having trouble in the 3rd part of my Scripting homework.
1.23 LAB: Warm up: Variables, input, and type conversion
(1) Prompt the user to input an integer between 32 and 126, a float, a character, and a string, storing each into separate variables. Then, output those four values on a single line separated by a space.(2) Extend to also output in reverse. ***(3) Extend to convert the integer to a character by using the 'chr()' function, and output that character.***
It seems to come up fine when I run the program but when I submit for grading I get 0 points. Here's my code:

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_char = input('Enter character:\n')
user_str = input('Enter string:\n')

print(str(user_int) + " " + str(user_float) + " " + str(user_char) + " " + user_str)
print(str(user_str) + " " + str(user_char) + " " + str(user_float) + " " + str(user_int))
print(str(chr(user_int)) + " " + str(user_float) + " " + str(user_char) + " " + user_str)
```

Comment: If it runs fine I do not believe that Stackoverflow is the right place to ask this question. How do you expect anyone on this platform to know a) the platform and b) the 'correct' answer? Try contacting your teacher instead.

Comment: I'm new to scripting and my teacher suggested this website for help, and I didn't realize this question would offend anyone. Very sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: For assignment number '3', you are putting out all four items, but it looks like only output the `int` converted to a character.

Comment: I am sorry, obviously you are new and I didn't mean to be harsh. I just meant to point out that the people here probably won't be able to help you about this particular issue.#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few remarks on your code.

`one`:

```
print(str(user_int) + " " + str(user_float) + " " + str(user_char) + " " + user_str)
```

It is not necessary to cast `user_char` to `str`. It is already a string.

```
print(str(user_int) + " " + str(user_float) + " " + user_char + " " + user_str)
```

`two`:

```
print(str(user_str) + " " + str(user_char) + " " + str(user_float) + " " + str(user_int))
```

Again you have cast `usr_char` (and `user_str`), to `str` and it isn't necessary as they are already strings and don't require casting to `str`.

```
print(user_str + " " + user_char + " " + str(user_float) + " " + str(user_int))
```

`three`:

And as I remarked in my comment above, (and I may be wrong), I think the specification only requires you to print out the character decoded from the `user_int`.

```
print(chr(user_int))
```

The changes I suggested could be rendered like the following.

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_char = input('Enter character:\n')
user_str = input('Enter string:\n')

print(user_int, user_float, user_char, user_str)
print(user_str, user_char, user_float, user_int)
print(chr(user_int))
```

(Note that I didn't add spaces between the items as printing a comma separated list of items adds a space between each item. Also, you can print the `user_int` and `user_float` without casting them to `str` and python will accept them. It is necessary to cast them to `str` if you are concatenating them to (spaces in your approach). (However, it seems your instructor wants you to cast them, so you should probably use your approach adding spaces between each item in your print statements and don't use my approach that uses a comma separated list).

Running this program, I got this sample result below.

```
Enter integer (32 - 126):
122
Enter float:
3.1415
Enter character:
B
Enter string:
Tom likes watermelon
122 3.1415 B Tom likes watermelon
Tom likes watermelon B 3.1415 122
z
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked and satisfied all 3 portions of the question.

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_char = input('Enter character:\n')
user_string = input('Enter string:\n')

print(user_int, user_float, user_char, user_string)
print(user_string, user_char, user_float, user_int)
print(user_int, 'converted to a character is', chr(user_int))
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just had this lab in Zybooks. I modified another users answer because it only passed 2/5 tests. This will pass all.

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))

user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_char = input('Enter character:\n')
user_str = input('Enter string:\n')

print(user_int, user_float, user_char, user_str)
print(user_str, user_char, user_float, user_int)

print(user_int, 'converted to a character is', chr(user_int))
```